# jQuery autocomplete with large array (9500) performance

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm loading in a JSON file into an array, then passing that array to jQuery autocomplete to use as its data source.

What I'm trying to achieve is when the autocomplete text box has focus all the available options are displayed and I've managed to get this working with the code below. The problem I have is that the array has around 9,500 entries and is very slow to load, is there anyway of improving performance? Or is 9,500 just to large of an array?

**Loading JSON file**

```
        $.getJSON("./json/airportdata.json", function(data){
            for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
                arrival_airports.push(data[i]);
                //console.log(data[i]);
            }
        });
```

**Autocomplete code**

```
        $( "#ajax" ).autocomplete({
            source: departure_airports,
            minLength: 3,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#ajax" ).val(ui.item.value);
            }
        } );
```

**Triggering autocomplete on focus**

```
        $("#ajax").focus(function() {
            $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
        });
```

Comment: you aren't showing how you load the data or pass it to plugin

Comment: @charlietfl sorry, will add those code snippets in now.

Answer (score 0):

yeah 9k cell array could mean trouble. Is there a specific reason for you to load all possible results in advance? You should probably look into loading specific recordset upon searching. So when a user is typing the search phrase, only then you should be pulling the relevant results.
ie:

```
    $('#search').autocomplete({
    source: 'serverSideToAcceptTheSearchPhrase.php', //you should expect the variable "term" to be sent via GET to this page on execution
    minLength: 2, //optional > this will allow a trigger of the search only when 2 or more characters inserted
    delay: 1000, // optional > this will allow a wait time of 1 sec between each keys before executing
    select: function(event, ui) {
        // function to trigger on "select"
    },
});
```

Comment: The reason for loading them all in advance is for the design / requirements to show a full list. At the time not realising there'd be 9,500 of them. From what I can tell there isn't going to be away around the performance issue but I'm also not all that knowledgeable in the area so was hoping there was something I didn't know.